# How to change REQUEST_URI in apache2?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

How to change `REQUEST_URI` in apache2 so my PHP script will get the changed version without redirection?

For example `REQUEST_URI` is:

```
/server/data
```

I want it to be REQUEST_URI:

```
/data
```

This way the changed `REQUEST_URI` will be passed to my PHP script and I will receive `/data` instead of `/server/data`.

I tried mod_rewrite, but it doesn't change REQUEST_URI variable

Comment: Do you want a redirect? See docs for [REQUEST_URI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) matching.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I would like to do it without a redirect. Is it possible?\

Comment: Removing REQUEST_URI in APACHE will cause problems when ever you want to access a directory! I would do what I want in htaccess instead, this might help is well https://serverfault.com/questions/790460/apache-modrewrite-strip-part-from-request-uri-in-rewritecondition also I think your question should go that site.

Comment: When you know you need to process this in PHP, you could simply do a `str_replace();` without causing any problems.